# How to show a secondary vertical axis to the right of a chart when using charts module?

Tags: charts

I have created a chart of two variables, using [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module. To do so, I used the Views integration of the charts module, and selected 'Chart' as the views style.

The result I got so far is that the chart is shown using the same vertical axis (y-axis) on the left (one for each variable).

Question: Is it possible to use two vertical axes, so that the primary axis is shown on the left of the chart, and the secondary on the right?

Comment: Note (from the current charts maintainer ...): if using a version of charts that includes the fix for issue #2327917, then select 'Charts' as the views style instead. If you also have the Chart module enabled and you'd select chart instead, you're using the Views integration from the Chart module, not from Charts ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answer here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2208461 (Courtesy of Quicksketch)

It is now incorporated in the (brand new) [Charts community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/233753), within [Use sub-charts to create dual-Y-axis charts](https://www.drupal.org/node/2426929#dualyaxischarts), which details the 4 steps to create such charts.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Drupal Answers. Could you please rewrite your answer so that includes the essential parts from the link.